# Undefined Control sequence while using \chapter command

Tags: chapters, document-classes

I am a new Latex learner and was following a guide. I created a template document. I used \chapter{} command to make a new chapter but i got an error stating undefined control sequence. if i remove this command the file shows results as expected.

[image]
This is my Tex code.

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{First \LaTeX{} article}
\author{Syed Ahmed  \\Electrical Dept. UET  \and {Talha Shabbir} \\ USPCASE NUST}
\date{February 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
First document. This is a simple example, with no
extra parameters or packages included.
\section{Mathematics Section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Einstien's Equation
    \begin{equation}
        E = mc^2
    \end{equation}
    Where  \\ E = Energy \\ m = mass \\ c = Speed of Light
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
    \item L'Hopital's rule 
    \begin{equation}
        \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f^{'}(x)}{g^{'}(x)}
    \end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Maxwell's Equations
       \[\nabla \cdot \textbf{D} = \rho\]
       \[\nabla \cdot \textbf{B} = 0\]
       \[ \nabla \times \textbf{E} = - \frac{\partial \textbf{B} }{\partial t}\]
       \[\nabla \times \textbf{B} = \mu_0j + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t}\]
\end{itemize}
\begin{abstract}
    The importance of water has been always vivid from the dawn of history. During the early stages of human evolution, the human ancestors used water for just the basic life need to sustain however with passage of time humans began to utilize water for other purposes such as irrigation, storage, cleaning, hygiene etc. However the use of water today is at much larger scale as compared to anything in the past of humanity. This led to the shortage of drinkable and usable water all around the world. Different methods and techniques have been proposed and implemented to clean the water from different facilities and sectors. One of the major cause of water pollution is contamination due to the dying chemicals in textile industry. This article proposes a new technique to not just clean the polluted water but also make it drinkable by purifying in much more affordable and environmental friendly way as compared to the conventional techniques. 
    \newline \textbf{Keywords:} Water contamination, water treatment, Dye water cleaning.
\end{abstract}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Number System}
bgjkjkjk
\end{document}
```

and this is the online overleaf project link.
https://www.overleaf.com/2427273277jcfqjtyzpbnr

Comment: Use `\documentclass{report}` instead of `article`. An article doesn't have `\chapter` command defined by default. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of research i found out that chapter command is only available in Book (or report) documentclass. i was trying it in article class.

Answer (score 0):

Leslie Lamport basically created the default LaTeX document classes. You should read his manual, Leslie Lamport "LATEX A Document Preparation System, User's Guide and Reference Manual", Addison-Wesley, 1994 and later.

In it he says "The article documentclass does not contain the `\chapter` command, ...". (But it does appear in his `report` and `book` classes`).

No research needed just read the basic documentation.

When trying to answer a question it helps if you know what you are talking about. --- GOM